# How to customize FancyBboxPatch for matplotlib .text(x, y, label, bbox)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a custom border-style for matplotlib text objects. I use them to visualize the nodes of a graph. I draw them like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
bbox_style = {
    'facecolor': 'white',
    'edgecolor': 'deepskyblue',
    'boxstyle': 'Round4', # here i would like to add some 
    'pad': 1
}

fig.text(.5, .5, "label", bbox = bbox_style)
```

Which results in this:

[image]

How can I modify the edge style to look something like this:

[image]

I assume I have to create a custom FancyBboxPatch class but I can't figure out how I can pass them to the text function (or create this custom class in general) I hope someone can help me with this! Thanks already in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derive your own box style for instance from [`Round`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.BoxStyle.html#matplotlib.patches.BoxStyle.Round) and overwrite the `transmute` function to return your custom path. Then pass it as the `'boxstyle'` value in the `bbox` dict.
From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyBboxPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyBboxPatch) of the `boxstyle` parameter:

> The style of the fancy box. This can either be **a BoxStyle instance** or
> a string of the style name ...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mp

class MyBoxStyle(mp.BoxStyle.Round):
    def __init__(self, pad=0.3, rounding_size=None):
        super().__init__(pad, rounding_size)
        
    def transmute(self, x0, y0, width, height, mutation_size):
        # your customization here
        # for this example we just return the standard Round implementation 
        return super().transmute(x0, y0, width, height, mutation_size)

bbox_style = {
    'facecolor': 'white',
    'edgecolor': 'deepskyblue',
    'pad': 1,
    'boxstyle': MyBoxStyle()
}

fig = plt.figure()
fig.text(.5, .5, "label", bbox = bbox_style)
```